# Website Administration Location + PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm building an online dating website at the moment.
There needs to be an admin backend to the site to approve users/photos etc.

I can add this admin part of the site/login etc to the same domain.
eg: www.domainname.com/admin

Or from my experience with PHP CURL I can put this site on a different domain and CURL the requests through.

Question: is it more secure to put the admin code/site on a completely different domain? or it really doesn't matter if it sits on the same domain? hacking/security is the really point of this.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it might be more secure if you ran it from a different server and hosted it on a subdomain using a different IP/vhost, or use a proxy mod for your webserver (see [Apache mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)) to proxy requests from yourdomain.com/admin to admin.otherdomain.com and enforce additional IP or access control using .htaccess or equivalent to access the proxy url.

Of course, if those other domains are web accessible, then they are only as secure as the users and passwords that use them.

For corporate applications, you may want to make the admin interface accessible from a VPN connection, but I don't know if that applies to you.

If there is a vulnerability on your public webserver that allows someone to get shell access, then it may make it slightly more difficult to get administrative access since they don't have the code for the administration portion.

In other words, it can provide additional security depending on the lengths you go to, but is not necessarily a solid solution.

Using something like cURL is a possibility, but you'd have far less troubleshooting to do using a more conventional method like proxy or subdomain on another server.